# Sweet Alert 2 is not working properly in Rails 7 Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sweetalert2, ruby-on-rails-7, ruby-3

I attempted to integrate the **Sweet Alert 2** java-script library for customising standard alert boxes into a Rails 7 application, but I received the following **error message: "Swal is not defined."**
I'm using Ruby 3 and Rails 7.

I initially attempted to use the "**sweet-alert2-rails**" gem in my Rails application, but there are no current updates available. I therefore attempted to accomplish this using import map, and I did so by running the following line.

```
bin/importmap pin sweetalert2
```

On top of that, I added the lines below to the **application.js**

```
import Swal from "sweetalert2"
```

I encountered the aforementioned problem when attempting to use "Sweet Alert 2" in my **view files**.

```
Swal.fire(
  'Good job!',
  'You clicked the button!',
  'success'
)
```

To integrate Sweet Alerts into my Rails application, I used these links.

https://sweetalert2.github.io/

https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined **Swal** in application.js using `import Swal from "sweetalert2"`, and then you are trying to use it in your view files, so it is saying that Swal is not defined.

Previously, in rails 6, we added "**sweet alert**" using "yarn install," and the same error occurred. Hence, to solve this error either in Rails 6 or in Rails 7, you need to add the following line inside your **application.js**.

```
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
window.Swal = Swal;
```

Adding **window.Swal** will undoubtedly fix your problem in Rails 7.

---

You can find references on my blog and in my GitHub repository. I have written this article for Rails 7.0.4 and Ruby 3.1.0. and also implemented the code for the same version.

Blog : https://rutikkpatel.medium.com/sweet-alert-2-in-ruby-on-rails-7-3f4cffe1ea5f

GitHub Repository : https://github.com/rutikkpatel/Sweet-Alert-Rails

**I hope that will help you with your issue.**